# C++ float/double to accurate string representation

Tags: c++

I have a problem getting a correct/accurate string representation of float/double/long double values.

I have this function that attempts to get a string representation of a floating point value:

```
template <typename T>
std::string double_to_string(const T& v) {
  static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
                "T is not a floating point type");
  std::stringstream sstr;
  sstr.setf(std::ios::fixed | std::ios::showpoint);
  sstr << v << std::ends;
  return sstr.str();
}
```

I invoke it with float, double and long double values, but do not get a correct/accurate string representation of the actual value I pass in to the function:

```
// float:
std::cout << double_to_string(77777777777777.7777777f) << std::endl;
// double:
std::cout << double_to_string(77777777777777.7777777) << std::endl;
// long double:
std::cout << double_to_string(77777777777777.7777777L) << std::endl;
```

The output I get is as below:

```
// float: 
77777780867072.000000

// double:
77777777777777.781250

// long double:
77777777777777.777779
```

Is there any way I can get an accurate string representation of float/double/long double values in C++?

(p.s. I'm using g++ 7.2.0)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use external libraries?

Comment: You can't get an accurate string repesentation because the `float` and `double` can't store the value accurately. According to wikipedia, a 32 bit float has a precision of 6-9 digits (15-17 for 64 bit), and that's what we observe here.

Comment: @Carl Yes, probably I can. Can you suggest anything please?

Comment: What are your requirements? In mathematics there are no "float" or "double" numbers. There are real numbers. Floats and doubles are (inexact) representations of real numbers in a computer. They need not be represented any further. One cannot represent all real numbers exactly in a computer.

Comment: Your question is (incorrectly) marked as a duplicate, so I cannot post a proper answer. The answer is [std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)

Comment: They never explained why it was marked as duplicate. I read that supposed previous answer, but that doesn't solve my problem. Do you have any clues about this std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 thing please?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` is how many digits in the string representation are safe to convert to the floating point T and back to the string resulting in the same string value. For `float`, it's 6, that's why you have 6 of `7`s in your output. For `double`, it's 15 - check again. For `long double`, it's 18 - so you are just lucky to have 19. Then, there is `std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10` - it is how many digits you need to have in your string to convert from floating point to string and back and end up with the same value. It's bigger than `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10`.

Comment: That's, of course, the mantissa part. For the exponent, you have `min_exponent` and `max_exponent` in the same [numeric limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Kit.

Answer (score 3):

Number `77777777777777.7777777` can not be exactly represented by floating-point number: `float`, `double`, or `long double`. Instead the closest representable floating-point number will be chosen. Since floating-point types have different precision float's closest number is farther than long double's.